# ¿Por qué no puedo hacer funcionar este botón más de una vez?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Quiero hacer un panel para editar entradas de un blog y que el usuario pueda aplicar ciertas opciones al hacer click en unos botones que aparecen cuando se mantiene el mouse encima de alguna entrada. Tengo este código:

```
var triangulo;
var btn;
var parametros;

if ($('.pausa').length > 0) {
    $('.pausa').on('click',function(e){
        parametros = {
            "pausar":$('.pausa').val(),
            "id":$(this).parents('div').attr('data-id'),
            "entr":$(this).parents('div').attr('id')
        }
        triangulo = $(this).parents('section').children('article');
        btn = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/funciones/pausar.php',
        data: parametros
    }).done(function(response) {
        $(".resultado").html(response);
        triangulo.prepend('<div class="triangulo"></div>');
        btn.remove();
        btn.prev('a').after('<input type="button" class="btnIndex_pb pausa_inac" value="d">');
    });
}

if ($('.pausa_inac').length > 0) {
    $('.pausa_inac').on('click',function(e){
        parametros = {
            "pausar_inac":$('.pausa').val(),
            "id_inac":$(this).parents('div').attr('data-id'),
            "entr_inac":$(this).parents('div').attr('id')
        }
        triangulo = $(this).parents('section').children('article').children('div');
        btn = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'includes/funciones/pausar.php',
        data: parametros
    }).done(function(response) {
        $(".resultado").html(response);
        triangulo.remove();
        btn.remove();
        btn.prev('a').after('<input type="button" class="btnIndex_pb pausa" value="p">');
    });
}
```

En este caso, la función que hace el botón `$('.pausa')` es llevar unos datos por Ajax a PHP para que se edite esa entrada en la base de datos y dicha entrada no aparezca en el blog, como decir que se desactiva sin borrar sus datos, solo para que los usuarios del blog no la vean.

El botón `$('.pausa_inac')` viene haciendo la función contraria, habilitar la entrada.

Este código anda bien, pero solo ocurre una vez, luego tengo que recargar la página si quiero volver a pulsar ese mismo botón en la misma entrada. Por ejemplo, si me he equivocado al pausar la entrada 1 en lugar de la 2, tengo que recargar la página en lugar de simplemente volver a presionar el botón para quitar la pausa de la entrada 1.

Aquí es donde se cargan los botones en el html trayendo algunos datos desde PHP:

```
<div class="contBtnIndex_pb btnIndex" data-id="<?=$id_blog?>" id="blg">
  <a href="editar.php?entr=blg&id=<?=$id_blog?>"><p class="btnIndex_pb edit">/</p></a>
  <?php if ($blogBajo['estado'] == "pausa") { ?>
     <input type="button" class="btnIndex_pb pausa_inac" value="d">
   <?php } else { ?>
     <input type="button" class="btnIndex_pb pausa" value="p">
   <?php } ?>
   <a href="editar.php?entr=blg&id=<?=$id_blog?>"><p class="btnIndex_pb eliminar">x</p></a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema principal es que intentas ejecutar un evento en un elemento recién creado.

**Explicación de porque pasa:**

> Javascript añade los eventos cuando carga la página, si eliminas los elementos que tienen dicho evento y vuelves a añadir elementos no tendrán dicho evento

**Solución:**

En vez de poner: `$('.pausa_inac').on('click',function(e){` 

Cambialo por: <s>`$(document).on('click','.pausa_inac',function(e){`</s>

' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' `$(padre).on('click','.pausa_inac',function(e){`

Esto hace que al hacer click en el documento si el elemento clickado cumple el selector `.pausa_inac` se activa el evento

**Edición:**

Con el `document` fuerzas la lectura del documento nuevamente limitando el rendimiento del mismo cuando es el `hijo` que es el único que cambia.

Comment: Lo puse como dices, pero ahora no me crea el boton que hace la acción contraria. Me borra el boton `.pausar` o `.pausar_inac` indistintamente.

Comment: Intenta poner el ```btn.remove();``` en la última línea a ver si es por eso

Comment: Efectivamente, ahora funciona. Muchas gracias por el dato, me ayuda mucho ;)

Comment: te recomiendo aplicar el selector al elemento `padre` de `.pausa_inac` ya que aplicarlo directamente al `document` fuerza la lectura del documento nuevamente limitando el redimiento del mismo cuando lo unico que deseas es darle el delegate al `hijo` que es lo unico que cambia. ejemplo: `$(padre).on('click','hijo',function(e){`

Comment: Ya lo añado a la solución, que es mejor como tu dices

Answer (score 0):

Vaya! A mi me paso algo similar, es porque cuando pones un boton en un input lo que sucede es que el input realiza la accion una vez y se reinicia, en vez de usar un input type button utiliza un simple botton, es decir, sustituye esta linea:

```
<!-- sustituye esta linea -->
<input type="button" class="btnIndex_pb pausa" value="p">
<!-- por esta de aca abajo --> 
<button class="btnIndex_pb pausa" value="p">
```